# Parameter not being passed to shell script copyfile.sh: 1: copyfile.sh: [d: not found

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, sh

I am trying to pass a simple parameter to a shell script. here is the script:

```
if ["$1" == "d"]; then

        if ["$2" == NULL]; then
            echo "Please enter the local location of the files"
        else
            LOCAL = $2
            scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem $LOCAL ubuntu@XX.XX.194.202:~/test/
        fi

    else
        scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/files/binaryhustle/ ubuntu@XX.XX.194.202:~/test/
    fi
```

I type: sh copyfile.sh d and the error I get is `copyfile.sh: 1: copyfile.sh: [d: not found`

Comment: Since when do we not put a space after the command?

Comment: sorry not sure what you mean? This is my first shell script

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're using double equals sign (==) I could assume that you're using an advanced shell like Bash. With normal shells, you could only use one `=` e.g.

```
if [ "$1" = d ]; then
```

For the above code, think of `"$1"`, `=`, `d` and `]` as 3 separate arguments for `[` just like any other command so spaces are necessary to separate them. If you did `["$1"` it would be like trying to run `"[$1"` instead. What only `if` does is decide the flow of the script depending on the result of the command(s) in front of it, and `[` generally could return 0 (success/true) or 1 (failure/false).

It's actually equivalent to:

```
if test "$1" = d; then
```

Also, there is no NULL keyword in shell scripts. You have to compare with an empty string

```
        if [ "$2" = '' ]; then
```

Or use `-z`:

```
        if [ -z "$2" ]; then
```

For bash it's recommended to use `[[ ]]`. It's a special syntax and is not like '[' or 'test' which are executed like other commands. It's a little more interpreted on a higher level. With it arguments are not subject to pathname expansion or word splitting even without quoting the variables.

```
if [[ $1 == d ]]; then

        if [[ -z $2 ]]; then
```

Although I would still recommend quoting second arguments for literal strings with variables to prevent reinterpretation due to varying implementations of bash with every versions, probably the older ones.

```
[[ $var == "$xyz" ]]
```

And also you can't place spaces on assignments:

```
        LOCAL=$2
```

And it's always a good idea to quote your arguments with variables to prevent [word splitting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-word-splitting) and [pathname expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-pathname-expansion).

```
        scp -r -i ~/Dropbox/Business/aws/first.pem "$LOCAL" ubuntu@XX.XX.194.202:~/test/
```

Comment: wow this helped heaps, I should also mention that by running bash instead of sh I overcame some of my problems, I did this after you told me about == being a part of bash syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Shell scripts are *really* particular about white spaces, so the if conditions should be written like so:

```
if [ "$1" == "d" ]; then
```

Also, the comparison to NULL may not work, but this should do the trick:

```
if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
```

Answer (score 0):

The brackets in the `if` statement need space after `[` and before `]`:

```
if [ "$1" == "d" ]; then
```

If you don't put the space, then the shell sees `[d` since you substituted the `d` for `$1` in the string `["$1"`.

Also if you are checking for `$2` to be empty, you can't do it by comparing with `NULL`. `NULL` is not a pre-defined shell empty string. You need to do it this way:

```
if [ "$2" == "" ]; then
```